# Reactive Cocoa - UITextView's rac_textSignal doesn't get called when programmatically setting text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, reactive-cocoa

I'm implementing a chat UI, and using Reactive Cocoa to adjust the chat bubble's size as the user types. Currently, I'm updating the UI's layout based on the textview's `rac_textSignal`. Everything's working great - except for one bit: when the user *sends* the message, I programmatically clear the textfield:

```
_inputTextView.text = @"";
```

... but the textview's `rac_textSignal` doesn't activate. [I hear this is a feature with ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/765) - but what's the proper way to build this? Do I need to have an NSString holding the `currentlyTypedString`, and drive the UI changes when that string updates?

Comment: I know this question is kind of old but if you just use `RACSignal.combineLatest([self.textView.rac_textSignal(), RACObserve(self.textView, "text")]` yadda yadda yadda. That way you subscribe to both UI and programatic updates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, that's correct.

Under [MVVM](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveViewModel?source=c#model-view-viewmodel), the *view model* should be considered the canonical source of UI data and events (which leads to a whole host of important benefits, like better testability). You'd store the typed `NSString` on the view model, then bind *that* to the UI.

With MVC, you'd have to use the controller or model instead, but the principle is the same: treat the view as transient data and do the important stuff elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

Just send action:

> [self.inputTextView
>   sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

Answer (score 0):

The following is a workaround that works:

```
[[RACSignal 
  merge:@[self.inputTextView.rac_textSignal, RACObserve(self.inputTextView, text)]] 
  subscribeNext:^(NSString* text) {
      // do something here
  }];
```

[Thanks to startupthekid](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/765#issuecomment-46082387) on GitHub.